# cf push error for .war file (Pivotal Web Services)

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

Have used Gradle for building a simple Hello World REST Controller.

Generated .war file is executing well at localhost:8080, But cf push helloApp -p build\libs\temp.**W**ar is unsuccessful. [cf push helloApp -p build\libs\temp.**J**ar works well, when deployed to cfapps.io.]

cf logs indicate something like ... Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletCon‌​tainerCustomizer.

Have taken care of including *providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'* in build.gradle, and overriding *configure()* by extending *SpringBootServletInitializer*.

springBootVersion = '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'

Comment: What version of the Java buildpack are you using when pushing your application? It would appear to be incompatible with Spring Boot 2.0.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I tried "cf push testEx -p build\libs\TestExample.war -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git", instead of "cf push testEx -p build\libs\TestExample.war" and deployment was successful! In the earlier case, cf logs indicate "OUT -----> Java Buildpack v4.5 (offline) | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#ffeefb9", whereas now "OUT -----> Java Buildpack 9f97630 | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#9f97630". So what's the new Buildpack version... And is CloudFoundry, SpringBoot or developer expected to kept the latest version updated.

Comment: @Vinay share your dependency file

Comment: Did you get it working @Vinay. I am having same issue.